# JavaScript: Adding/removing layers from ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript

I've developed an application which loads the services from the `ArcGIS` Server via `REST API`.

Each service has multiple layers, and I can check/uncheck any layer. The problem is the layers are loaded via one URL, and each time I have to remove **all layers** of the service and load again.

Is there a better way?

Comment: No. Loading each layer as a service would be extremely wasteful of Server resources, and result in awful performance.

Comment: I don't understand. You have to remove all layers just to turn one off?

Comment: @Dowlers Is there another way?

Comment: Using javascript? Yes there are several.  layer.setVisibleLayers(ids, doNotRefresh?) is the easiest: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html#setvisiblelayers

Comment: @Dowlers Could you write in answer form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individual layers within a map service can be turned on or off using the esri javascript api. Look at the setVisibleLayers method of the dynamicmaplayer class: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html#setvisiblelayers

It takes on array of layerIDs to make visible

```
require([
  "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer" ,"dojo/query", ... 
], function(ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, query, ... ) {
  var layer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer( ... );
  var inputs = query(".list_item"), input;
  visible = [];
  for (var i=0, il=inputs.length; i< il; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].checked) {
      visible.push(inputs[i].id);
    }
  }
  layer.setVisibleLayers(visible);
  ...
});
```

Comment: How to define layers? `var layer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer( ... );` What is in the brackets?

Comment: Also, is says, `ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer` is not defined

Comment: I think you need to go back and look at some of the samples on the javascript api website. Instantiating layers is a core part of the api and is covered in many of the samples. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/map_twodynamic.html

Comment: What about `SetLayers` from https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/layers/dynamic-map-layer.html ?

Comment: Oh you are using leaflet. I'm not as familiar with that but I think you are right. The setlayers method will take an array of layerids to show.

Comment: I would close the discussion here, moving to https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/285056/116936