# ArcGIS REST API: hide/show layers

Tags: arcgis-server, leaflet, arcgis-rest-api

I've developed an application on `leaflet JS`, which loads the services from `local ArcGIS server` through `Arcgis REST API`.

The following code loads the service:

```
function addServiceToMap(service, layers = ""){

    if(service){

        let url = "http://domain/arcgis/rest/services/" + service + "/MapServer?layers=show:" + layers + "&token="+token;

        let new_service = L.esri.dynamicMapLayer({
          url: url,
          opacity : 1,
          useCors: false,
          f: 'image'
        });
        new_service.addTo(map);
    }
}
```

The problem is, to hide a layer, I have to call this function, showing the required layers in the URL. Therefore, I add the service repeatedly.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you mentioned the service could be a single layer or grouped. In my example below, the first layer (mcounty) just has layer 2 from the service (**layers: [2],**). 
The second method (fcounty) just has layer 2 defined in it's url. (**/MapServer/2**)

Even through these are basically the same service, in the layer control I can turn each on/off separately.

```
//MapService as a Dynamic Layer  //Symbology comes from ArcServer Service
    mcounty =  L.esri.dynamicMapLayer({
        url:'https://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Civil_Boundaries/MapServer',
        layers: [2],
        opacity : 1
    });

    mcounty.bindPopup(function (error, featureCollection) {
        if(error || featureCollection.features.length === 0) {
              return false;
            } else {
              return '<b>NY County</br> Name: </b> '+ featureCollection.features[0].properties.NAME;
            }
    });
//END MapService as a Dynamic Layer 

//MapService as a Feature Layer //Symbology comes from ArcServer Service or defined here.
    fcounty = L.esri.featureLayer({
        url: 'https://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Civil_Boundaries/MapServer/2',
        simplifyFactor: 0.5,
        precision: 5,
        style: function (feature) {
            return { 
            color: 'blue', 
            fillColor: 'green',
            weight: 2 };
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you want to show/hide a layer from the service, you have to send the URL again with new attributes?

Comment: Use the layer control to hide/show. https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/ Once you have defined the layer with your URL as source. Leaflet handles the callbacks as needed. The layer control handles the addTo(ma) and remove layers from the map.

Answer (score 0):

Use the layer control.

http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/layers-control.html

In addition, you can also bring in your mapservice as a featurelayer to have more control over symbology and popups.  As an example:

http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/ArcServer/EsriMapServer.html

Use the control to turn on/off the layers which are both mapservices.

Comment: The service comes with multiple layers in one callback. They are not received separately. How to access the layers?